# Important files and photos saved on Cloud service

Tags: icloud, dropbox, google, google-apps

What happens if the iCloud/GoogleDrive/DropBox data center where my important files (business info, family photos) are saved ever faces a catastrophic situation like a terrorist nuclear bomb attack? Is my cloud data stored in more than one geo-location?

Comment: Can data be geo stored? Yes. Are all companies doing it the same, no? This is quite broad and lacks a practical problem to be solved.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your data is stored in multiple different locations. Most of the time cloud services has various datacenters in multiple countries on different continents.

As user you don't know where your data is stored exactly and how many copies of that data is stored. But you can bet they have a backup of a backup of a backup.

Because systems, servers, harddrives fail every single day their systems are designed to keep all the data save.

Keep in mind companies can decide to stop offering cloud services. So if you are a little bit smart, you have backups as well.

Comment: The modern adage - even for consumer-level storage - is "Any data stored in fewer than three distinct locations ought to be considered temporary" ;)